# Default dark mode setting on KDE

Tags: kde

I use Arch Linux with KDE Plasma and want to tell websites that I prefer dark mode by default. For example, there is an option to select a theme on YouTube (device theme, light theme, dark theme) and the default is "device theme". My "device theme" is light by default, so all websites are light. I want to change this "device theme" to dark so that all browsers are dark by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It exists a "Dark mode" preference in GTK. A modern web browser, like Mozilla Firefox, is able to share this information to websites, who can then adapt their user experience according to your "Dark" preference. YouTube included.

### How to set the "Dark Mode" in KDE

Go to this menu, then Apply / Save:

```
System Settings > Plasma Style > Breeze Dark
```

If it does not work, do a logout and a login.

To me, it just worked immediately. This worked in my laptop with Debian GNU/Linux bullseye, with KDE Plasma Desktop 5.27, so I hope this should work on a lot of Unix-like distributions like Ubuntu and Arch Linux included indeed. I then visited some online Discourse forums and they had the black background. For example I visited https://forum.linux.it/ who is white / black according to this feature.

If you are using Arch Linux, read additional details here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dark_mode_switching

### Extra privacy concern

Note that the "Dark Mode" preference is an extra metadata that can increase efficacy of online fingerprinting. So it's easier to track your activity online even if you are not logged-in. If you are interested in extra privacy details, or if you want a counter-measure, see the Mozilla Firefox documentation:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-website-appearance-settings-firefox